# gradle: could not find oracle jdbc jar from maven repository

Tags: oracle, gradle, jdbc

Gradle build: could not find oracle jdbc jar from maven repository

```
> Could not find com.oracle.jdbc:ojdbc8:12.2.0.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/oracle/jdbc/ojdbc8/12.2.0.1/ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/oracle/jdbc/ojdbc8/12.2.0.1/ojdbc8-12.2.0.1.pom
```

It is actually in the maven repository

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle.jdbc/ojdbc8/12.2.0.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

see https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/maven-central-guide.html

it should be

```
implementation 'com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc8:12.2.0.1'
```

Comment: @Sunnyday No, it is in Maven Central: https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.oracle.database.jdbc

Comment: While Oracle only publishes their artifacts to MavenCentral, the dependencies are also available through JCenter. This is because it proxies MavenCentral, so from a user standpoint, you can configure Gradle to only use JCenter if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Check out the Gradle dependencies for Oracle JDBC driver on the [Maven Central Guide](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/maven-central-guide.html#gradle) page.